# Xamarin app crashes after upgrading Firebase.Crashlytics

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've updated the Xamarin.Android project with the latest Firebase (v118.2.1.2). Crashlytics packages. After I've applied appropriate changes in the code (removed Frabic related code, etc.), I run the build - everything is fine, but I'm getting a runtime error:

```
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.datatransport.Transformer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/11-17 15:25:15.884 E/AndroidRuntime( 5560):     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:584)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
```

I've installed all the lates Xamarin.AndroidX packages as well as the all dependencies of the FirebaseCrashlytics.

Seems to me that issue is related to the missing package, but it is kind of "hard to guess" which one)

Comment: have you try clear project & rebuild project?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, yeah. Lots of time. I've noticed that I clean & build project every single time, lol)) Even when there is no need for that)

Comment: try test it on a sample app to see if the problem still exist so we could know if there sth wrong in your project

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in my post, I assume there is a problem with dependencies.
I created a new project, added firebase.crashlytics package and everything works fine. But in my original project there are loads of packages. Hard to say which is is a root of problems. Anyway, that's really strange to get such errors, especially I can see from the logs that issue is rising on initialisation stage of firabse((

Comment: try debug the packages